# How can I bypass Cloudflare's hCaptcha with Selenium?

Tags: selenium, recaptcha, captcha, cloudflare, hcaptcha

I'm working on a bot that scrapes data from sites but the cloudflare hcaptcha is getting in the way.
Here is my current code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

#Vairables
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
WEBPAGE = "https://fame.omaze.com/6717638115418?title=Win%20a%20Tesla%20Model%20X®%20Plaid&handle=tesla-model-x-plaid-2022&variant_id=39865096831066&variant_price=$2&combo_campaign_id=6723156017242&combo_title=Win%20%24100%2C000%20to%20Fund%20Your%20Future&combo_variant_id=39883746836570"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get(WEBPAGE)
```